# Grid design for complex data design

Tags: gui-design, grid, web, information

[image]

The purpose of making the design grid / cards alike is to display the information directly to the users, so we avoid things like accordion, drop-down that could have hidden information.

The challenge is how we can explain what the data is, as the label can't be too short and too long. What's your recommendation based on your experience?

Comment: Am I right in assuming you're mostly asking about the labels on the fields along the right side ("Expected", "Finance – Audit/Tax", etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

You can try and leave obvious information without labels and small labels on the not to easy to understand information. Take a look at one of my past projects using this technique.

http://dribbble.com/shots/861482-List-Elements

Answer (score 1):

You need to look further into ways you can group & condense the data. For example, some like "total experience" don't really need a title if it's placed beneath the different years of experience.

Below's an example. I might have mangled the past experience section by pulling out the current(?) position. It felt strange when there's no name associated to the card.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7oGSe.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>